# Trying to import a private key into bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, client, api, private-key

I am in a special situation where I need to import my private key credentials and basically restore a wallet to bitcoind. bitcoind is running and I do have an rpc user/pass and server=1 in the bitcoind.conf, but no matter what I do, when I try and import the key I get the following error.
There is no password nor encryption on the wallet.

```
root@coined:/home#  bitcoind importprivkey "5JxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHjdCia9dt7" "root"
error: {"code":-4,"message":"Error adding key to wallet"}
```

Comment: Are there any useful messages in debug.log?  Also, FYI, if you run this on the command line, your private key is probably now logged in your shell's history file (perhaps ~root/.bash_history).

Comment: If you typed it up manually, you might have a typo in there or are missing a character? I once had a uppercase "S" instead of lowercase "s" in something and it took me forever to find it.

Comment: @Murch copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

Without anything in the log, it's difficult to day. But here are a few suggestions what could try to find out the cause of the error:

- Do you have write permission on the `wallet.dat` file in your `.bitcoin` directory?
- Is the wallet locked with a passphrase? Then you need to unlock it (would probably give another error message but worth asking).
- Did you set the `disablewallet` option either in command line or configuration file?
- Is your wallet possibly locked due to a `-reindex` operation?

Answer (score -2):

leave away the "" around the key (and the label)?

Comment: Same issue with or without the quotes.

Comment: Not a trace of the error in  /root/.bitcoin/debug.log  :(

Comment: I have tried with a new user as well.